# Did the Valar know there were still Faithful Númenóreans left on Númenor late Second Age?

Tags: tolkiens-legendarium, the-silmarillion

I've been pondering this, and I wonder if they distinguished faithful and non-faithful during the Ar-Pharazôn incident.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes. From "The Akallabêth":

> ... by grace of the Valar Elendil and his sons and their people were
> spared from the ruin of that day.

Comment: They were given forwarning too and their ships were pushed to safety if I recall